# Count unsigned integers with scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read input using scanf. I want to count all of the digits in the input. So for example the input: 0, 1, 2 3 4-5-67 should give 8. I'm not quite sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: If you want a parser, write a parser.  Why use `scanf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char input[50];
    int i=0;
    int totalNum=0;


    printf("Enter input : ");
    fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin); // get the whole input in one go ( much better than scanf )
    input[strlen(input)] = '\0'; //to get rid of \n and convert the whole input into a string

    for(i=0;i<strlen(input);i++){
        if(isdigit(input[i])!=0){ // built in function to check is a character is a number .. make sure you include ctype.h
               totalNum++;
        }
    }

    printf("Total numbers in the input  = %d\n",totalNum);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sukhvir@Sukhvir-PC ~
$ gcc -Werror -g -o test test.c

Sukhvir@Sukhvir-PC ~
$ ./test
Enter input : 12.3.567'4 45
Total numbers in the input  = 9
```

Comment: @Rolodecks hahah .. cool no problems .. please come back after you have 15 rep and upvote. Thanks

Comment: @Rolodecks also ask me if you are unclear about anything in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can do looping with `scanf` and `%c` for the format. Then you check whether the character is an integer or not. If it is, increment the counter, else do nothing.

Comment: What can I do to check if it's an integer?

Comment: @Rolodecks check my answer ( use the function called isdigit() )